# Keras IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds

Tags: neural-network, theano, keras

I'm new to Keras and im trying to do Binary MLP on a dataset, and keep getting indices out of bounds with no idea why.

```py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=20, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop')
model.fit(trainx, trainy, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16) # THROWS INDICES ERROR
```

Error:

```py
model.fit(trainx, trainy, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16)

Epoch 1/20
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-6-c81bd7606eb0>", line 1, in <module>
model.fit(trainx, trainy, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=16)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 646, in fit
shuffle=shuffle, metrics=metrics)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 271, in _fit
ins_batch = slice_X(ins, batch_ids)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 65, in slice_X
return [x[start] for x in X]

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 65, in <listcomp>
return [x[start] for x in X]

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1963, in __getitem__
return self._getitem_array(key)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2008, in _getitem_array
return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1371, in take
convert=True, verify=True)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3619, in take
indexer = maybe_convert_indices(indexer, n)

  File "C:\Users\Thiru\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1750, in maybe_convert_indices
raise IndexError("indices are out-of-bounds")

IndexError: indices are out-of-bounds
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Im able to run other models just fine

Comment: trainx and trainy should be numpy arrays

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Answer from the comment - trainx and trainy should be numpy arrays. You can convert the data frame to numpy array using `as_matrix()` method. I also faced this issue. It's weird that Keras does not give meaningful error message.

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for the same issue resolution for the auto-sklearn and pandas dataframe. The solution is to pass the X dataframe as X.values. I.e. fit(X.values,y)

Answer (score 5):

From the [official Keras Page:](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#training)

> Keras models are trained on Numpy arrays of input data and labels. For training a model, you will typically use the  fit function.

To convert a pandas dataframe to numpy array you can use `np.array(dataframe)`. For example:

```py
x_train = np.array(x_train)
```

Comment: With this, model thinks that string values like Urls are floats: "ValueError: could not convert string to float: "Clothing Girls' Clothing Baby Girls' Clothing Dresses"
"