# Indexerror: out of bounds for size error in keras convnet1D

Tags: python, numpy, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to use CNN 1D for time series prediction. I have a time series data set with 30 features, 3 targets and more than 3000 rows.

This is my keras model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(64, 10, batch_input_shape=  (100,30))) #100 time steps and 30 features
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=256,
                    filter_length=3,
                    border_mode='valid',
                    activation='relu',
                    subsample_length=1))

model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Convolution1D(nb_filter=150,
                    filter_length=3,
                    border_mode='valid',
                    activation='relu',
                    subsample_length=1))
model.add(MaxPooling1D())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(x,y)
```

The model compiles without any error but when I tried to do model fit it gave this error

```
IndexError: index 124 is out of bounds for size 64
Apply node that caused the error: AdvancedSubtensor1(embedding_17_W, Reshape{1}.0)
```

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36798335/996366) but my `x` (feature) and `y` (target) are already in numpy array form. How to solve this?

**EDITED**

After some tinkering I have found out the problem is caused by my CNN model itself. I tried to train the same dataset with a simple neural network and it ran with out any issue.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(30, input_dim=30))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dense(15))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('tanh'))
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer)

model.fit(x,y)
```

Any one know what is wrong with my CNN model?

Comment: Problem in your Embedding layer: instead of 64 should be `1 + max_index`

Comment: its showing the same error `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for size 1`

Comment: You don't understand me. See Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/): `input_dim: int > 0. Size of the vocabulary, ie. 1 + maximum integer index occurring in the input data` Your Embedding should be 125 or more. Evaluate `numpy.max(x)` and plus 1 (index 0 is reserved for unknown values).